# Using C# Entity Framework find a value based on 2 high low column values

Tags: c#, entity-framework

If the input value is between MinIncome and MaxIncome in my database table, I want to find the Amount db field value.  So for instance if an input was 1525 falling between 1500 & 1599, I would expect a return value of 75.
How do I write a Linq or Lambda statement for this?  Please see screen shot.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```cs
int income = 1525;
int amount = dbContext
    .MyDbSet // use DbSet Property here
    .Single(x => x.MinIncome < income && x.MaxIncome > income)
    .Amount;
```

This selects the only element where the condition is met, and returns the amount of that object.

You could also use `.Where(x => x.MinIncome < income && x.MaxIncome > income).Single().Amount` to achieve the exact same result.

Other options include `.SingleOrDefault()` which prevents errors in case no entry in your `DbSet` matches, `.First()` which prevents errors if multiple entries match, or `.FirstOrDefault()` if no entries or multiple entries can match.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```cs
var result = await DbContext
                     .Table
                     .Where(x => x.MinIncome <= value && value <= x.MaxIncome)
                     .Select(x => x.Amount).FirstOrDefaultAsync();
```

Comment: Thanks for thinking about this.